# Call sigaction using unintialized sigaction struct?

Tags: c, unix, signals

I saw the following usage in some code:

```
struct sigaction term_handler;  // global variable without initialization
...
sigaction(SIGTERM, &term_handler, NULL);  // install uninitialized sigaction for SIGTERM
```

This code seems to allocate a `sigaction struct` leaving all its members null or 0, which makes me really confused.
What would happen if SIGTERM is triggerred?

I took a test using following code:

```
struct sigaction int_handler;
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    sigaction(SIGINT, &int_handler, NULL);
    while(1) {}
    return 0;
}
```

and use "kill -2" to test, the process got killed any way. Does it mean that the process took default action related to its signal?

Answer (score 1):

`SIG_DFL` is zero on my system, so if you have a similar system, then it would cause SIGTERM to assume its default behavior.

This has no effect unless the behaviour of SIGTERM was previously modified (including before the program was `exec`uted). If it was, the default behaviour (killing the process) is restored.

---

The following demonstrates:

`a.c`:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static struct sigaction term_handler;

int main(int argv, char* argc[]) {
   if (argv && strcmp(argc[0], "1") == 0)
      sigaction(SIGTERM, &term_handler, NULL);

   kill(getpid(), SIGTERM);
   sleep(2);
   return 0;
}
```

`harness.c`:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void test(const char* arg) {
   pid_t pid = fork();
   if (pid) {
      int status;
      waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
      printf("%d\n", WIFSIGNALED(status) ? WTERMSIG(status) : 0);
   } else {
      struct sigaction term_handler;
      char * const newargv[]    = { "./a", arg, NULL };
      char * const newenviron[] = { NULL };

      term_handler.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
      sigaction(SIGTERM, &term_handler, NULL);

      execve("./a", newargv, newenviron);
   }
}

int main() {
   test("0");
   test("1");
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./harness
0     # Without sigaction in child, wasn't killed by a signal
15    # With    sigaction in child, was killed by TERM
```

Comment: My explanation was correct. It was my test that was wrong. Undeleted answer. Tests shown.

Comment: So it seems make no sense if sigaction is not previously set, and isn't a good way to switch back to default sig handler either. Since no description can be found about this in documents, should I say that the result will be undefined and depends on platform?

Comment: As I mentioned and demonstrated, it can be set by the calling program, so how you possibly know whether it was previously set or not (unless your program is only called by one other?). /// I have no idea how portable `SIG_DFL == 0` is. I doubt you'll have issues there, but it would be clearer if you added an `assert` or explicitly set `sa_handler = SIG_DFL;`

Comment: Switched test program from Perl to C.